# porque la Imagen de galería no se sube al servidor web?

Tags: android, cámara, imagen, upload

Estoy desarrollando una app con 2 opciones para subir imágenes al servidor web:
 "Tomar foto con cámara" ó "Elegir foto de galería"
Mi problema es al tratar de subir la imagen seleccionándola desde la galería, 
No se que puedo estar haciendo mal..

Al momento de seleccionar la imagen de galería me muestra esto en el logcat:

```
05-23 10:36:16.211 24386-24386/mx.gob.lahuerta.oficiadepartes I/BitmapFactory: DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : value is null. res : null
```

Este es el codigo de mi app:

```
 fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           showOptions();

        }
    });

subir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                serverUpdate();
            }
        });
```

**Aqui muestro las opciones para capturar la imagen**

```
private void showOptions(){
        final CharSequence[] option = {"Tomar foto", "Elegir de galeria", "Cancelar"};
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Modificar.this);
        builder.setTitle("Elige una opción");
        builder.setItems(option, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                if(option[which] == "Tomar foto"){

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
                        //Verifica permisos para Android 6.0+
                        checkExternalStoragePermission();
                    }

                    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), MEDIA_DIRECTORY);
                    boolean isDirectoryCreated = file.exists();

                    if(!isDirectoryCreated)
                        isDirectoryCreated = file.mkdirs();

                    if(isDirectoryCreated){
                        Long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
                        imageName = timestamp.toString() + ".jpg";
                        mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + MEDIA_DIRECTORY
                                + File.separator + imageName;
                        newFile = new File(mPath);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(newFile));
                        startActivityForResult(intent, PHOTO_CODE);
                    }


          }else if(option[which] == "Elegir de galeria"){

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(intent.createChooser(intent, "Selecciona app de imagen"), SELECT_PICTURE);

                }else {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
```

**Metodo para caputurar foto con la camara**

```
private void getCamara(){

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
        //Verifica permisos para Android 6.0+
        checkExternalStoragePermission();
    }

    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), MEDIA_DIRECTORY);
    boolean isDirectoryCreated = file.exists();

    if(!isDirectoryCreated)
        isDirectoryCreated = file.mkdirs();

    if(isDirectoryCreated){
        Long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
        imageName = timestamp.toString() + ".jpg";

        mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + MEDIA_DIRECTORY
                + File.separator + imageName;

        newFile = new File(mPath);

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(newFile));
        startActivityForResult(intent, PHOTO_CODE);
    }

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        switch (requestCode){
            case PHOTO_CODE:
                MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                        new String[]{mPath}, null,
                        new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                                Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                                Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> Uri = " + uri);
                            }
                        });
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mPath);
                imagen.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                nombreImagen.setText(imageName);
                subir.setEnabled(true);
                break;

            case SELECT_PICTURE:

                Uri path = data.getData();
                imagen.setImageURI(path);
                imageName = path.getPath().substring(path.getPath().lastIndexOf("/")+1)+".jpg";
                nombreImagen.setText(imageName);
                subir.setEnabled(true);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Metodo para subir la foto al servidor**

```
private void uploadFoto(String imag){
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://xxx/WebService/upload.php");
    MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
    ContentBody foto = new FileBody(newFile, "image/jpeg");
    mpEntity.addPart("evidencia", foto);
    httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);
    try {
        httpclient.execute(httppost);
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private boolean onInsert(){
    HttpClient httpclient;
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
    HttpPost httppost;
    httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
    httppost= new HttpPost("http://xxx/WebService/upload.php"); // Url del Servidor
    //Añadimos nuestros datos
    nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("evidencia",imageName+".jpg"));

    try {
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        httpclient.execute(httppost);
        return true;
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}

private void serverUpdate(){
    if (newFile.exists()){
        new ServerUpdate().execute();
    }
}

class ServerUpdate extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        uploadFoto(foto);
        if(onInsert())
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(Modificar.this, "Exito al subir la imagen",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        else
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(Modificar.this, "Sin exito al subir la imagen",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Modificar.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Actualizando Servidor, espere..." );
        pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        pDialog.show();
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}

private void checkExternalStoragePermission() {
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "No se tiene permiso para leer.");
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 225);
    } else {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "Se tiene permiso para leer!");
    }
}
```

**Anexo el error del logcat al presionar el boton "subi**r"

```
05-24 10:56:09.651 28020-28020/mx.gob.lahuerta.oficiadepartes E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: mx.gob.lahuerta.oficiadepartes, PID: 28020
                                                                                java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.io.File.exists()' on a null object reference
                                                                                    at mx.gob.lahuerta.oficiadepartes.Modificar.serverUpdate(Modificar.java:502)
                                                                                    at mx.gob.lahuerta.oficiadepartes.Modificar.access$300(Modificar.java:83)
                                                                                    at mx.gob.lahuerta.oficiadepartes.Modificar$6.onClick(Modificar.java:323)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697)
                                                                                    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10826)
                                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Espero su ayuda! :(

Comment: Puedes verificar si en el LogCat recibes algun error o aviso sobre `OutOfMemory ` ??

Comment: hola @sioesi no obtengo ningún error o aviso sobre OutOfMemory.. Pero agregue el error que recibo en el logcat, puedes revisarlo? te agradezco la atención.

Comment: Aun No puedo solucionar mi problema..Ayuda!!!!..por favor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno... Batallando mucho mirando otros ejemplos por fin obtuve una solución a este problema, Lo comparto por si alguien mas le surge algo parecido.

Hice las siguientes modificaciones en el método showOptions(), cambiando los Intent que se encuentran dentro de la opción de "Elegir de galería"

```
else if(option[which] == "Elegir de galeria"){
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                try {
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Selecciones un administrador de archivos"),SELECT_PICTURE);
                }catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex){

                }
```

y en el método "onActivityResult" cree un nuevo método para obtener el Uri Absoluto

tambien cree el archivo newFile relacionandolo con la Uri Absoluta

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode){
        case SELECT_PICTURE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                subir.setEnabled(true);
                Bitmap photobmp;
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                String dataFU = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);
                newFile = new File(dataFU);
                photobmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(dataFU);
                imagen.setImageBitmap(photobmp);
                imageName = dataFU.substring(dataFU.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
                nombreImagen.setText(imageName);
                break;
            }
        case PHOTO_CODE:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                        new String[]{mPath}, null,
                        new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                                Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                                Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> Uri = " + uri);
                            }
                        });
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mPath);
                imagen.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                nombreImagen.setText(imageName);
                subir.setEnabled(true);
                break;
            }
    }
}
```

y este es el metodo para obtener la imagen

```
 public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri){
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }finally {
        if (cursor != null){
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

subir la imagen capturando la de cualquiera de las dos Opciones "Elegir de Galería" o "tomar Foto"

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que la instancia de file tiene valor null,

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'boolean java.io.File.exists()' on a null object reference

Debes asegurar que el archivo exista o que el path sea correcto, al parecer el error se encuentra en este bloque de código, tratas de abrir un archivo mediante su ruta, pero este archivo en realidad no ha sido creado.:

```
  Long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
    imageName = timestamp.toString() + ".jpg";

    mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + MEDIA_DIRECTORY
            + File.separator + imageName;

    newFile = new File(mPath);
```

Comment: Hola, Te comento que ese bloque de codigo lo utilizo para subir la imagen tomada con la camara, y de esa marera si funciona.. Creo que necesito hacer algo similar para subir la imagen desde la galeria pero no encuentro la forma

Comment: como puedo adaptar ese bloque de codigo que me comentas, para que guarde la imagen en un "File", ya que siento que eso es lo que me falta...

Comment: aun no puedo solucionar mi problema... Ayuda!!!! por favor...